# docker-machine create keeps asking for password

Tags: docker, openssl, docker-machine, openssh

I am attempting to `docker-machine create` to a Ubuntu 16.04 host like this:

```
    ssh-keygen -R ${remote_host}
    ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_host_rsa.pub root@${remote_host}

    docker-machine create \
        --driver generic \
        --generic-ip-address=${remote_host} \
        --generic-ssh-key ~/.ssh/id_host_rsa \
        --generic-ssh-user=root ${machine_name}
```

Version information:

```
docker --version
Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c

docker-machine --version
docker-machine version 0.16.2, build bd45ab13
```

I am repeatedly asked for a password .. Why is this?

Here is the output:

```
...

Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: Received disconnect from 77.68.21.66 port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
ERROR: Disconnected from 77.68.21.66 port 22

Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(production) Importing SSH key...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Password: 
Detecting the provisioner...
Password: 
Provisioning with ubuntu(systemd)...
Password: 

.. etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this problem was the ordering of `~/.ssh/config`.

I had a `Host *` entry in `config` first, before that of my corresponding specific server `Host XX.XX.XX.XX` entry.

I moved the wildcard entry at the end of `~/.ssh/config` and now the password is no longer constantly asked for and the problem is now fixed.

I how this helps someone.